# WAS Liberty 8.5.5.4, JPA 2.0 - discovered implementations: NONE

Tags: java, jpa, websphere-liberty

I was able to get JPA working with eclipse Luna and installing eclipseLink (and created a User Lib with the 3 jars).

However, I have now moved to Rational Application Developer (RAD) and attempting to use the JPA that is delivered with WAS Liberty.  I initially used RAD JPA facet to configure JPA and then edited persistence.xml.

I am getting this error:
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "test2" after trying the following discovered implementations: NONE

I assume (always dangerous) the NONE is a configuration error and I cannot do anything until that is resolved...

I have copied the wlp\dev\api\spec\com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.1.jar into WEB-INF/lib and included that in my java build path.

As you can see below, I was guessing my provider was not correct, and tried several values...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="test2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider-->
    <!-- provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider-->
    <provider>com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/New Generic JDBC</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.ibm.analytics.jpa.Dimtask</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="RM"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:netezza://netezza-1.site.ibm.com:5480/DATABASENAME"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jspoon"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.netezza.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What else can I do to get past the NONE?

Here is the updated version of persistence.xml, I just commented out the provider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="test2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider-->
    <!-- provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider-->
    <!-- provider>com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider-->
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/New Generic JDBC</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.ibm.analytics.jpa.Dimtask</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="RM"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:netezza://netezza-1.boulder.ibm.com:5480/BACC_TST_ISHANGO_DW"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jspoon"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="C0ke4y0u"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.netezza.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I created my Entity class using JPA Tooling, and using a simple junit test to call a named query.  The first step is to create the EMF and it is a static in my class (so none of the test is actually running, it is failing at instantiation creating the static variable):

```
static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "test2" );
```

This is the exact same code as used before with eclipse and eclipseLink.

Comment: Seems I did the XML include wrong...  and it is too large for comment...

Comment: some additional info...  I am able to access the db ok and used the JPA Tooling to create an Entity class from a table.

Comment: You need to add jpa-2.0 feature in server.xml. You also want to remove provider definition from persistence.xml

Comment: <featureManager>
      <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
      <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
I did remove the <provider> 
Still getting the error.

Comment: Did you put wlp\dev\api\spec\com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.1.jar in your application to attempt to debug or was it always there? If it was always there I'd suggest removing it and trying again. You might not be using the javax.persistence APIs you think you are.

Comment: Thank you for the help and ideas.  It is getting the one expected, because when I double click to open the file, it is attempting to open "The JAR file C:\LibertySrvr\wlp\dev\api\spec\com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.1.jar has no source "

But I went ahead and removed it from the application and build path and got the same error.

Comment: A few things... Please update your post with your current configuration(removing the provider stanza). Also, can you better describe what you're doing when you get this exception? ... are you trying to run in the server, or a JUnit?

Comment: Rick, thanks for looking.  I have updated my original post with that info.

Comment: This morning I created a User Lib and put the com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.1.jar inside it.  I then edited the JPA properties and changed JPA implementation to User Library.  I included the library in the build path.  However, this did not help.

Comment: I have now packaged the 3 jar files required from eclipseLink and added them into a User Lib and then used that User Library in the JPA properties and got past the EMF creation issue.  This makes me believe that I am missing some required jar to use the Liberty JPA.  Currently I am only using com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.1.jar.